# Build app with react really efficient?

Tags: reactjs

Building app with react with flux, I'm wondering developing an app with react is really efficient.

With flux all states are maintained by domain. All state of components have to manuplate in flux. I need to normalize data structure to consume in react components. This is verbose.
 And more components are listed we have to consider rerender optimization. This is time consumer stuff.

Of course reusing react components is nice but configuring, designing, planning are also complex.

I need some advice of using react.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very overwhelming at first as there are so many decisions to be made. Just do a google search for "JavaScript fatigue" and you will realize you are not alone.

Fortunately, there are lots of great resources out there (both free and paid) to learn about all of this stuff. I personally used Cory House's two React courses on Pluralsight to get up to speed and found this route very helpful.

Still, project setup can be very time consuming with flux or redux, and you have to consider whether your application is complicated enough to warrant their use. React itself is extremely flexible and can be used in a simple application on it's own, or even in conjunction with other frameworks or tools like backbone.

There are plenty of things out there to help ease some of the pain of setting boilerplate for a react project.

- https://github.com/coryhouse/react-flux-starter-kit
- https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot

Both of those are good resources (there are many more out there as well) and serve as good starting places.

Lastly, Facebook just the other day released an official tool that allows developers to start writing react apps without having to worry about any configuration. There are still some limitations to the tool, but it seems very promising and looks like a great place to start for beginners.

- https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html